# Startup image on iOS changes size

Tags: ios, iphone, web-applications, webkit

Just starting a web app for iPhone and have defined images / icons / viewports / tags etc but on startup the splash image displays for a moment and then changes size / moves down the screen when the menubar kicks in.

http://testsite2.origincreative.com

Anyone know a way around this?

Comment: give some screen shot

Comment: It happens so quickly it's almost impossible to grab a shot - if you visit the URL and add it you homepage on iOS you can see it happening clearly though.